# spring batch job repository configuration with jboss 7 and oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g, spring-batch

I realized OracleLobHandler has been depreciated and DefaultLobHandler is preferred. I would like to ask, what do I replace the nativeJdbcExtractor with?

```
<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean"> 
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
<property name="transactionManager" ref="jobTransactionManager" /> 
<property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED" /> 
<property name="lobHandler"> <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.**OracleLobHandler**"> <property name="nativeJdbcExtractor"> 
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.JBossNativeJdbcExtractor"/> 
</property> </bean> </property> </bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

[OracleLobHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/lob/OracleLobHandler.html) seems to be deprecated in Spring 3.2.

In [DefaultLobHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/lob/DefaultLobHandler.html), do you see any `nativeJdbcExtractor` field? 
No, so you can't set any `nativeJdbcExtractor` anyway... Just try to not replace it.

Check the doc:

> Deprecated: in favor of DefaultLobHandler for the Oracle 10g driver
>   and higher. Consider using the 10g/11g driver even against an Oracle
>   9i database! DefaultLobHandler.setCreateTemporaryLob(boolean) is the
>   direct equivalent of this OracleLobHandler's implementation strategy,
>   just using standard JDBC 4.0 API. That said, in most cases, regular
>   DefaultLobHandler setup will work fine as well.